# Repeating a function a set amount of times in python

Tags: python, function, loops, jython, repeat

I am doing an intro class and they are asking me to repeat a function a certain amount of times, as I said this is an intro so most of the code is written so assume the functions have been defined. I have to repeat the `tryConfiguration(floorplan,numLights)` the amount of time `numTries` requests. any help would be awesome :D thank you.

```
def runProgram():
  #Allow the user to open a floorplan picture (Assume the user will select a valid PNG floodplan)
  myPlan = pickAFile()
  floorplan = makePicture(myPlan)
  show(floorplan)

  #Display the floorplan picture

  #In level 2, set the numLights value to 2
  #In level 3, obtain a value for numLights from the user (see spec).
  numLights= requestInteger("How many lights would you like to use?")

  #In level 2, set the numTries to 10
  #In level 3, obtain a value for numTries from the user.
  numTries= requestInteger("How many times would you like to try?")

  tryConfiguration(floorplan,numLights)

  #Call and repeat the tryConfiguration() function numTries times. You will need to give it (pass as arguments or parameterS)
  #   the floorplan picture that the user provided and the value of the numLights variable.
```

Comment: We're happy to help you with these problems on StackOverflow, but please post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Loop in the range of numTries and call the function each time.

```
for i in range(numTries):
      tryConfiguration(floorplan,numLights)
```

If using python2 use `xrange` to avoid creating the whole list in memory.

Basically you are doing:

```
In [1]: numTries = 5

In [2]: for i in range(numTries):
   ...:           print("Calling function")
   ...:     
Calling function
Calling function
Calling function
Calling function
Calling function
```

Comment: For a large value of `numTries`, use [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead.  The difference being that `xrange()` will not create a very large list  in memory before starting the loop.

Comment: @JamieCockburn, I edited for xrange, xrange is only needed for python2

Answer (score 1):

First let me double check if I understood what you need: you have to place `numTries` sequential calls to  `tryConfiguration(floorplan,numLights)`, and each call is the same as the others.

If it is so, and if `tryConfiguration` is synchronous, you can just use a for loop:

```
for _ in xrange(numTries):
  tryConfiguration(floorplan,numLights)
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something: there could be other solutions, like leveraging closures and/or recursion, if your requirements are different.

Answer (score 0):

When we're talking about repeating a certain block of code multiple times, it's generally a good idea to use a loop of some kind.

In this case you could use a "for-loop":

```
for unused in range(numtries):
    tryConfiguration(floorplan, numLights)
```

A more intuitive way (albeit clunkier) might be using the while loop:

```
counter = 0
while counter < numtries:
    tryConfiguration(floorplan, numLights)
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Typically in python, we also use `__` to indicate an unused value: `for __ in range(numtries): ...`